# Angularjs Fadeout then Fadein onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm trying to fadeout a div element or paragraph, change the text inside of it, and fade it back in.

I am currently using the code below with jquery but would like to know how i could do the same with angular.

i tried quite a couple of things (angular-animate might implement it wrong) but has not really worked. i have just found the jquery option working. but i would like to expand my knowledge on angular and angular animate.

```js
$("#main").fadeOut(25, function() {
        $(this).html('html');
        $(this).fadeIn();
    });
```

See the Pen [Random Quote Machine](https://codepen.io/DiamessoGroup/pen/dWPLgz/)

Comment: See [AngularJS Developer Guide - Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/animations) and [AngularJS ng-show Directive - Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow#animations).

Comment: @georgeawg i will dive in the docs. Thanks.